# How to reinstall Windows and not lose my MS Outlook configuration?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spell-check

I cannot find a portable version of MS Outlook. [Discussions](http://office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/m/26972/) mentions backing up the .PST file, but I would like to backup ***all*** configuration data, address book, email, footers, out of office message, etc, right down ot font settings if possible.

It may sound trivial, but what annoys most is the loss of auto-correct spelling data which was built up over years.

As an alternative, I cannot find a [free, portable email client which auto-correct](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/free-portable-windows-email-client-with-auto-correct-spelling) and Thunderbird does not have an [auto-correct plugin which works with the current version](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38916/auto-correct-spell-checker-for-thunderbird).

So, how can I best back up MS Outlook’s configuration? All of it.

- From within Outlook?
- by copying files regularly? (which?)
- by exporting registry hives ? (which, and how to automate?)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Locating-the-Outlook-data-files-0996ece3-57c6-49bc-977b-0d1892e2aacc) (unless *you* saved stuff elsewhere) backing up `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook` and `%APPDATA%\Outlook` should be enough for mails, addresses and likely their settings. Check Documents folder for safety.

If you want to also save dictionaries, forms, signatures and templates unfortunately, you'll have to dig some other folder then. In `%APPDATA%`: Forms, Signatures, Stationery, Templates, UProof.

Comment: "some other folder" ... I guess I will do some searching for files with unique words from  "forms, signatures and templates". This is a good start, though (+1)

Comment: Actually, they are those "some other folders" mentioned in the article. I just didn't want to mention them because personally I find them trivial 99% of times.

Comment: Maybe best give all available info & let others decide what's good for them ? ;-)  +1  Do you want to add them to your answer (in case of link rot), or shall I?

Comment: Done. Besides, it's not like every link rot cannot be fixed by Wayback Machine.

Comment: The one in Canada, at least ;-)